# Is there a way to show import errors in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, video

When importing video files into iTunes (through either *File > Add to Library*, drag and drop, or the automatic import folder), is there a way to show errors or a log explaining why a file was not imported?

When using the automatic import folder, the rejected file is moved into the *Not Added* folder, but iTunes doesn't give any reason why the file was rejected. Is there a way to enable logging in iTunes to show what went wrong (e.g. *wrong audio codec*)?

Comment: not checked - but Console would be the most likely place to find it

Comment: In my experience Automatic Import Folder does not work well at all. It often appear things in Not Added for no reason, and manually import them fixed it without issues.

Comment: Nothing in Console when importing - no messages related to import when I filter for "itunes".

Comment: Tried all ways of importing, same result in all cases, the file does not show up in iTunes, no message indicating why it was rejected.